# Force shell for in ssh config

Tags: shell, ssh

I use a `Match exec ...` in my .ssh/config for some rules. (Specifically, I change my ProxyJump based on my IP address). In the man page it explains

> The exec keyword executes the specified command under the user's shell.  If the command returns a zero exit status then the condition is considered true.  Commands containing whitespace characters must be quoted.

I use two shells with fairly different syntax (zsh and xonsh) which makes it difficult to write one exec statement that works equally well on both. Is there a way to force ssh to pass the exec command to a specific shell rather than using the user's shell?

Note that this is executed with the local shell and is not related to which shell runs on the remote server.

*Edit 2021-09-09:*

Here's some more details. I have the following in my ssh config:

```
match !exec "ifconfig | egrep -q 'inet (123\.45\.|67\.89\.)'"
    ProxyJump hop
```

This is bash syntax. The single quotes force raw string interpretation, so the slashes are passed to egrep.

In xonsh, this syntax is illegal due to python string quoting rules. I would have to use `r'123\.'` to disable quoting. Note that I can't work around this by calling a different shell inside the exec command because the string quoting still is performed by the outside shell, which may change depending on the current value of $SHELL.

Comment: Can't you use `zsh -c command` or whatever the equivalent is for `xonsh`?

Comment: "The user's shell" means "your *login* shell", not the shell where you type `ssh …`; so the fact you use two shells doesn't matter, unless you `chsh` often. Or unless you want the same config to work in two machines/accounts where your login shells are indeed different. Please confirm you know it's about login shell and yet the question stands.

Comment: @terdon Wrapping with zsh doesn't change the value of `$SHELL`. It does work if I explicitely set the shell, e.g. from xonsh call `$SHELL=/bin/sh ssh ...`. However this doesn't work if ssh gets run as a subprocess, so I would have to do this for many commands (e.g. sshfs, ssshuttle, etc)

Comment: Why would `$SHELL` be relevant? That's just your user's default login shell for the system. If you want ssh to use zsh, then just have `zsh /path/to/script.zsh` in the .ssh/config file. I may be missing something, of course, so it would help if you could [edit] your question and include specific examples.

Comment: $SHELL is relevant because ssh forks $SHELL to execute the `exec` commands.I've added my example to show that the interpretation of the command string depends on the shell, so it's not possible to just call zsh within the config file

Comment: I don't get two things: (1) You know what your login shell is, so you can modify your `~/.ssh/config` accordingly. No single config file needs to deal with two shells, unless you `chsh`. Do you `chsh` daily? For separate users (possibly on separate machines) there are separate config files anyway. Adjust each file to the login shell of the respective user. (2) Even if you `chsh` daily, `zsh /path/to/script.zsh` is a valid command in both shells in question, isn't it?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski 1) I use iTerm on macOS. This sets $SHELL for each terminal independently, so I often have multiple terminals with different shells simultaniously. Maybe you are used to linux where chsh is the only way modify $SHELL and it is always consistent with /etc/passwd. 2) There is no way to construct an argument to `zsh -c` that is is consistent across both shells due to the different quoting rules.

Comment: (1) OK, now I get it. (2) Forget about `zsh -c`, my comment was about `zsh /path/to/script.zsh`. What is the problem with it?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I didn't think about making the exec statement run a wrapper script. It's a good idea. If you right it up as an answer I might accept it.

Comment: `zsh /path/to/script.zsh` first appeared in [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/664359/108618#comment1258953_664359) from @terdon . The only thing I did with it is being persistent in bringing it to your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been unable to find a way to force a particular shell from within ssh config files. I believe the only option is to choose one shell and make sure that any way of launching ssh sets `$SHELL` correctly.

This can be achieved in a few ways. For these examples I assume that my ssh_config uses bash syntax and I want to call it from xonsh, but it should be equally possible to use any combination of incompatible shells.

### Wrapper scripts

One approach would be to add a wrapper script early in the `PATH` which sets SHELL correctly:

*~/bin/ssh:*

```
#!/bin/bash
# Set the shell to use within .ssh/config
SHELL=/bin/bash exec /usr/bin/ssh "$@"
```

Then make it executable (`chmod +x ~/bin/ssh`).

*~/.xonshrc or your calling shell's configuration file:*

```
# Prepend to PATH
$PATH = p`~/bin` + $PATH
```

This would have to be done for any tool that uses `.ssh/config` (e.g. sshuttle, sshfs, etc).

### Xonsh aliases

For my xonsh-specific solution I went with an alias function.

*~/.xonshrc*:

```
def bash_shell(cmd):
    import functools
    def alias(cmd, args):
        with __xonsh__.env.swap(SHELL="/bin/bash"):
            ![@(cmd) @(args)]
    return functools.partial(alias, cmd)
aliases |= {
    'ssh': bash_shell('ssh'),
    'sshuttle': bash_shell('sshuttle'),
    # ...
}
```